# How do I use pretty URLs in Yii without a root path?

Tags: php, yii, url-routing, yii2

I turned on pretty URLs in Yii according to the docs

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-routing.html

and the home page is visible, but when I try to go to another URL, it gives me an error.

http://localhost:81/xxx/web/shopping/search?q=toaster

> The requested URL /xxx/web/shopping/search was not found on this server.

I tried to create a generic rule, but it didn't help.

```
    'urlManager' => [
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'enableStrictParsing' => false,
        'rules' => [
          // ...
          '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
        ],
    ],
```

The docs specifically say not to include the subfolders in the path.

> Note: Rules with server names should NOT include the subfolder of the entry script in their patterns. For example, if the application is under http://www.example.com/sandbox/blog, then you should use the pattern http://www.example.com/posts instead of http://www.example.com/sandbox/blog/posts. This will allow your application to be deployed under any directory without the need to change your application code.

Must I list every single route explicitly? I tried to give an explicit route for

```
'shopping/search' => 'shopping/search',
```

But it didn't help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It was because of Apache. Without pointing to `index.php`, Apache didn't know where to send the request and is the one giving the error. This will default to `index.php`.

```
# For pretty URLs
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php
```

https://komarashettynageshrao.wordpress.com/2010/02/04/pretty-urls-in-yii/

Comment: Sure thing. There are no limitations regarding subfolders, the quote you mentioned applies to the rules with server names.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    'urlManager' => [
            'class' => 'yii\web\UrlManager',
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'showScriptName' => 'false'
    ],
```